# Adding List view to Canvas

Tags: android, listview, canvas

Hi 
Is it possible to add a custom list view to a canvas and rotate the canvas to some degrees so that the list view seems to be rotated

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by overriding the draw() method in a ListView subclass, but if the change is minor, it actually may be easiest to simply apply a rotation animation such as this one:

```
    RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 3,0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    getListView().startAnimation(anim);
```

Note that this uses the 2.3-and-below compatible animation framework (not the newer 3.0+ only framework), which means that the view isn't *really* rotated, it only *looks* rotated -- this means clicks still register as if the list was in its original position, which for changes more than a few degrees will noticeably mess up drag/scroll/click interactions (in which case you'll want to go with actually overriding [`draw(Canvas canvas)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) in a custom ListView subclass and apply the necessary transformations).